# Remove button after 30 minutes. Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm making a discussion forum and I want to remove the users ability to edit the comment they made after 30 mins.

This is the code for my button in the vue.js, it's not a "real" button, it's a clickable icon

```
<div class="btn-link-edit action-button"
    @click="edit(comment)">
    <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i>
</div>
```

method in vue.js

```
edit(model) {
    this.mode = 'Editar';
    this.form = _.cloneDeep(model);
    this.dialogFormVisible = true;
},
```

What would be the best way to add this timer, the timer should start right when the user makes the comment, in the table for this I have a field called `comment_time` with that information.

How can I do this?

Comment: See https://cushionapp.com/journal/reactive-time-with-vuejs for being able to react to time changes in Vue. You don't want to use a timer-based approach; it'd fail if the user refreshed the page.

Comment: @ceejayoz I'm still confused, what about when the user makes more than one comment? the user can also reply to someone else's comment.

Comment: What about it? By treating time reactively, you can show (or not) the edit button based on the individual comment's timestamp compared to the current timestamp, even if the user refreshes the page or comes back tomorrow. Replying has nothing to do with any of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do that is:

Here in template:

```
<div id="app">
    <div v-for="comment in comments">
      <p>
      {{comment.text}}
      </p>
      <button v-if="commentTime(comment.comment_time)">Edit </button>
    </div>

    </div>
```

Vue script:

```
    new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    comments: [
      { text: "Nancy comment", comment_time: 1579206552201}
    ]
  },
  computed: {
    now () {
      return new Date()
    }
  },
  methods: {
    commentTime(cTime){
         let t = new Date(cTime)
         t.setMinutes(t.getMinutes() + 30)
       return this.now.getTime() < t.getTime()
    }
  }
})
```

You can show the result here:
[your code in jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/svxqo23w/4/)

Answer (score 0):

First, start by putting `v-if="canEdit"` on your `<div>`. Then in your script section of the Vue component we're going to create a `canEdit` boolean, then a loop to update it on a regular basis. This assumes you have a specific `Comment.vue` component and `this.comment` is being passed to the component already, maybe as a prop or something, and that it contains the typical Laravel Model fields, specifically `created_at`.

```js
data() {
  return {
    canEdit: true, // Defaults to `true`
    checkTimer: null, // Set the value in `data` to help prevent a memory leak
    createdAt: new Date(this.comment.created_at),
  };
},
// When we first make the component, we set `this.createdPlus30`, then create the timer that checks it on a regular interval.
created() {
  this.checkTimer = setInterval(() => {
    this.canEdit = new Date() > new Date(this.created_at.getTime() + 30*60000);
  }, 10000); // Checks every 10 seconds. Change to whatever you want
},
// This is a good practice whenever you create an interval timer, otherwise it can create a memory leak.
beforeDestroy() {
  clearInterval(this.checkTimer);
},
```

Comment: will this be affected by the page being reloaded?

Comment: When the page reloads, it will create a new `checkTimer` value and start updating it every 10s. If you want different functionality, it should be easy enough to change in the `created()` method.